# upgrade visual studio to sp1

Tags: visual-studio, upgrade, .net-3.5

i'm going to install sql server 2008 on my computer,during preparing the installation there was an error like this:

a previous release of Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 is installed on this computer. Upgrade Microsoft visual studio 2008 to sp1 before installing SQL Server 2008.

So i should upgrade my visual studio to sp1, but i don't know how to do it.

Please help, and Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the installer for SP1 and run it.

It is [on this page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

Easier Method

> There is a registry trick to overcome this error
>
> Go to
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\9.0`
>
> rename 9.0 to 9.0old
>
> then click “re run”  ,it will solve the problem,but better to install
>   visual studio 2008 SP1

Source: http://computech.in/2010/08/a-previous-release-of-microsoft-visual-studio-2008-is-installed-on-this-computer-upgrade-microsoft-visual-studio-2008-to-the-sp1-before-installing-sql-server-2008sql-server-2008-installation-failed/